# Stripe payment : Can I manage subscription from diffrent Application for next billing

Tags: magento, stripe-payments, magento-1.9, recurring-billing

My client's customers placed subscription/recurring order from [clickfunnels](https://app.clickfunnels.com/) and now he want to manage these recurring orders from Magento for next billing. [Cryozonic Stripe Subscriptions](http://store.cryozonic.com/) module is installed in Magento store. Anyone can guide me is this possible by custom code or any alternate way?

Looking forward positive response.

Comment: You can retrieve the upcoming invoice via the API: https://stripe.com/docs/api#upcoming_invoice

Comment: by using this I can see the upcoming invoice, but in my case I want to create invoice for next billing from different platform/application. Please advise!

Comment: Yes, it is possible by custom code.

Comment: Thanks for positive response @Enigmativity. Could you please let me know how can I achieve this? Is there any tutorials available?

Comment: @LalitKaushik - You question only asks if it is possible.You should read [ask]. Also, asking for "any alternate way" is off-topic here. This is a programming only site. And so is asking for tutorials. You should come here with code you've written and ask for help on it.

Comment: @Enigmativity what shunning answer :)
How could you say "any alternate way" is off-topic? I think I post my question here to get solution not for only YES, NO or Off Topic

Comment: @LalitKaushik - Any alternative way than coding means it is not about coding and therefore it is off-topic here. From the on-topic help page, valid questions must be "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".